# Why am I getting a Null Reference error for my DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, nullreferenceexception

So this is my Sum() method for my grid view.

```
private double CellSum()
{
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        double d = 0;
        Double.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), out d); // runtime error
        sum += d;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Whenever I click the button I get call the Sum() method, which returns the total of a column.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = CellSum().ToString();
}
```

How do I sum the total of a column? I remember pulling this code somewhere on this site but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

I only have 3 columns and I didn't set any properties so it's default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Value` is probably returning null, which will cause `ToString()` to blow up.

Try this instead:

```
Double.TryParse(Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value), out d);
```

`Convert.ToString()` will return an empty string if the string being converted is null, while `ToString()` just throws an exception.

Now if `Value` is null, `d` should contain 0, so you can keep the rest of the code the same.